# Size of Program Counter

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

What would be the size of Program Counter in terms of bits? Is the size always fixed in all types of system architectures?

Comment: No, of course it's not fixed.  It's typically the same size as other pointer registers (i.e. ones that can be used for indirect addressing of data).

Answer (score 1):

The Program Counter is a special purpose Register that holds the address of the instruction being executed or of the next instruction to execute (this seems to depend on the architecture). Consequently it has the size of a machine word i.e. 32, 64 etc. bits.

Comment: "word size" / "machine word" can be debatable and hard to pin down.  e.g. AVR is an 8-bit RISC microcontroller architecture with 8-bit integer registers.  Pointers are pairs of registers.  So it's probably more accurate across more ISAs to say that **the program counter register has pointer width**, i.e. the address size of the machine.  (That's even true on segmented x86 if we consider IP as the near pointer, and CS:IP as the far-pointer version of the program counter).  I assume there are some ISAs where this doesn't hold up, maybe with narrower code vs. data pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The program counter is simply the location of the instruction being executed, and so it will change based on the processor architecture. That is, a 64 bit architecture will need 64 bits to hold the program counter, a 32 bit will need 32, and so on.

Comment: The value of PC during the execution of an instruction is often the address of the *next* instruction.  e.g. x86-64 RIP-relative addressing mode encodes the rel32 displacement relative to the *end* of the current instruction (aka start of next).  Branch displacements are also relative to the end of the current instruction.  MIPS works the same way for relative branches.  32-bit ARM does branches relative to 2 instructions later, exposing a pipeline detail of early implementations.

Answer (score 0):

A program counter is one of  the  register used in computer architecture and os. It holds the address of next instruction to be executed. After  instruction is executed, it will incremented by one,(PC =PC +1) moreover program counter will  be point to the next instruction. It is mainly used in conditional jump and un conditional jump instruction to calculate the effective address .

Comment: Most architectures have instructions wider than 1 address unit, and some are variable length.  So PC += instruction_length for non-branch instructions.  re: "mainly used" for branching: that's the main software interaction with it, but you could say that it's *mainly* used for fetching the next instruction.